# Difference between ServiceStack's web and dotnet-new tools

Tags: servicestack

ServiceStack currently seems to offer two tools for creating projects based on templates.

The `dotnet-new` (https://docs.servicestack.net/dotnet-new) and the new `web` .Net Core tool (https://docs.servicestack.net/web-new).

I created the same project type with both tools, and the result looked identical.

They seem very similar, so what is the difference or different uses of which tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both create the same project templates, the primary difference is that `dotnet-new` is an npm tool and requires npm installed whilst `web` is a .NET Core tool that requires .NET Core installed.

So they both can create the same project templates although the [web tool itself has a lot more other features](https://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v5.5#web-tool).